# How to set callback order invocation same as target function invocation

Tags: javascript, jquery, synchronization

I have a problem in my project.

To describe this issue I have wrote simplified code snippet:

```
function waitFor(fnReady, fnCallback) {
    var check = function() {
        if (fnReady()) {
            fnCallback();
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(check, 100);  // wait another 100ms, and try again
        }
    };

    check();
}


var result = 0;
var flag = true;
function ajaxRequest() {
    setTimeout(
         function() { flag = false; 
                     console.log('ping');
                    },3000
    );
}

function ajaxRequestHandler() {
    setTimeout(
         function() { flag = true; 
                      console.log('pong');
                    }, 200
    );
}
for(var i =0;i<10; i++){   
    waitFor(function() { return flag; }, ajaxRequest);
    waitFor(function() { return !flag; }, ajaxRequestHandler);
}
```

it returns:

```
ping - 10 times
pong - 10 times
```

desired result:

```
ping 
3 second timeout 
ping
---------------------
ping
3 second timeout 
pong
--------------------
.....
```

Can you help correct my code?

### UPDATE

Actual problem:

I have a google map.
I have a lot of places when I should to redraw it.

For application logic very important that If I send

```
request1
request2
request3
request4
```

I should handle responses in the this order

```
handle response of request1
handle response of request2
handle response of request3
handle response of request4
```

Problem that I don't know order of requests.

In different places of file I see following code rows:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'bounds_changed', renderTerminalsOnMapAndFitBounds);
...
$.getJSON('getAllTerminals.json', renderTerminalsOnMapAndFitBounds);
.....
$.getJSON('getAllTerminalsInsideRectangle.json', renderTerminalsOnMapAndFitBounds);
...
$.getJSON('getAllTerminalsInsideCircle.json', renderTerminalsOnMapAndFitBounds);
...
$.getJSON('getBigTerminals.json', renderTerminalsOnMapAndFitBounds);
........
```

`renderTerminalsOnMapAndFitBounds` method sends request to server and in succes alternative render result on map. But this event happens very often

Comment: How is this different than your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691226/ping-pong-behaviour-using-deffered?  Async behavior in JS should not be done by polling.  It should be done by just harnessing the completion callbacks already provided.  Also, these questions would probably be better to be real use cases with real code rather than the way you've phrased them as theoretical discussions.

Comment: I got right answer to my question but I cannot use this way in my real application

Comment: Now I am trying don't use deffered.

Comment: Then, show us the ACTUAL real problem you have, not some theoretical discussion.  Only then, can we offer you the best solution to your actual problem.  I stand by my comment that polling for completion of an async event is NOT the right way to code for async.  Use completion callbacks if you don't want to use promises.

Comment: I send a lot of ajax requests to server but server is very slow. Result of request I draw on map. But I send request1, request2, request3, but I can get  response 3, response2, response1. Thus results of response2 and response3 will be lost. Is it clear for you?

Comment: No, that is not clear to me.  Please edit your question to include a more detailed description of this actual problem.  Only then, can you take the most advantage of the help here.

Comment: @jfriend00 Topic updated

Comment: Please show your actual google maps request code so we can answer the question in the context of what you are actually doing.

Comment: This file 2000+ rows. There are more 5 places there I can send request to server... it can happen on different events

Comment: So, show us ONE piece of real code where you have this problem.  You don't seem to get that if you ask an abstract question, you get an abstract answer that may or may not actually help you (as proven by your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691226/ping-pong-behaviour-using-deffered)).  If you ask a specific question with REAL code, you get a REAL answer that you can actually use.  I'm personally not wasting my time again on an abstract answer, but I will help with a real answer with real code.

Comment: I have updated topiс. Is it more clearly now?

Comment: What is the desired result?  Are you wanting async results to be processed in the order requested?  even if they return in a different order?

Comment: @gstackoverflow _"I send a lot of ajax requests to server but server is very slow. Result of request I draw on map. But I send request1, request2, request3, but I can get response 3, response2, response1. Thus results of response2 and response3 will be lost. "_ . _"desired result:ping 3 second timeout ping"_ . Tried adding an id to ajax request , waiting for all requests to complete ; then sorting and displaying results in desired order after sorting id's ?

Comment: @guest271314 Can you provide more details. code example would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern

```
var map = "abcdefghi".split("");
var responses = []; // collect responses
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend : function(jqxhr, settings) {
      jqxhr.id = Number(settings.data.split(/id=/)[1]); // add `id` to `request`
        console.log(settings.data.split(/id=/)[1]);
    }
});
var request = function(id, data) {
    // append `id` to `id` data
    return $.post("/echo/json/", {json:JSON.stringify([data]), id:id})
};

$.each(map, function(k, v) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      request(k + 1, v)
      .done(function(data) {
        // do stuff at each response
        console.log(data); // note return values
      })
      .always(function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
          // do stuff at each response
          responses.push([jqxhr.id, data[0]]);
          // do stuff when all requests completed , results items in `responses`
          if (responses.length === map.length) {
              responses.sort(); // sort `responses` based on `id`
              // do stuff with `responses`
              console.log(responses);
          }
      });
    },1 + Math.random() * 1000) // async
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/g254bbjg/

Comment: Sorry, I am novice in javascript and this code is absolutely unclear for. Is it possible to bring closer your code to my initial code in question?

Comment: @gstackoverflow When `request` is made , an `id` is added to the `request` . When view `console` at jsfiddle, responses are received unsorted. `id` and responses from `request` are pushed to `responses` array. `responses` array is sorted , based on `id` , which should result in `responses` being ordered in the same manner in which `requests` were made. Should then be able to process `responses` in linear order; i.e.g., _"handle response of request1
handle response of request2
handle response of request3
handle response of request4"_ ; as `responses` should correspond to `request`s order.

Comment: You add id to request. How do you understand that response corresponds request?

Comment: If interpret question correctly , requests called in order _"For application logic very important that If I send request1 request2 request3 request4"_ ? If send in the above order , `id` should correspond to the order `request` sent; i.e.g., 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4. Added `setTimeout` to piece for async response . Note responses at `console` at jsfiddle. Piece attempts to utilize incrementing `id` then sort after all responses received , returning items to request order 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4. Could then process response handlers in same order 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> , even if response 8 returned before response 1.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use promises for this, but you've said no promises (not sure why), so here's a generic sequencer algorithm in plain javascript (tested in the jsFiddle linked below):

```
function sequence(fn) {
    // initialize sequence data upon first use
    if (typeof sequence.low === "undefined") {
        sequence.low = sequence.high = 0;
        sequence.results = {};
    }
    // save id in local variable so we can reference it in the closure from the function below
    var id = sequence.high;

    // advance to next sequence number
    ++sequence.high;

    // initialize the result value for this sequence callback
    sequence.results[id] = {fn: fn, args: [], ready: false, context: null};

    return function(/* args */) {
        // save args and context and mark it ready
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
        // get the results object for this callback and save info in it
        var thisResult = sequence.results[id];
        thisResult.args = args;
        thisResult.context = this;
        thisResult.ready = true;

        // now process any requests in order that are ready
        for (var i = sequence.low; i < sequence.high; i++) {
            var result = sequence.results[i];
            // if this one is ready, process it
            if (result.ready) {
                // increment counter past this result
                ++sequence.low;
                // remove this stored result
                delete sequence.results[i];
                // process this result
                result.fn.apply(result.context, result.args);
            } else {
                // if this one not ready, then nothing to do yet
                break;
            }
        }
    };
}

// your usage:

google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'bounds_changed', sequence(renderTerminalsOnMapAndFitBounds));
...
$.getJSON('getAllTerminals.json', sequence(renderTerminalsOnMapAndFitBounds));
.....
$.getJSON('getAllTerminalsInsideRectangle.json', sequence(renderTerminalsOnMapAndFitBounds));
...
$.getJSON('getAllTerminalsInsideCircle.json', sequence(renderTerminalsOnMapAndFitBounds));
...
$.getJSON('getBigTerminals.json', sequence(renderTerminalsOnMapAndFitBounds));
........
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/aqugm1fs/

---

Conceptually, what this does is as follows:

1. Pass a substitute completion handler in place of the normal completion callback.
2. This substitute function marks each response with a sequence id and saved the original completion handler.
3. If a response comes back while another response with a lower sequence id is still pending, then the result is just stored and saved for later.
4. As each response comes in, it processes as many responses in sequence as are ready

Note: while all the examples you have use the same callback function, this will work with any callback function so it would work with a mix of different types of operations.

Comment: Fixed a bug when used for 2nd sequence of events after first sequence had finished.

Comment: @gstackoverflow - where'd you disappear to?  I coded and tested a result to do exactly what you asked for and now you're gone.  Kind of makes us wonder why we bothered to try to help.

Answer (score 0):

my variant:

```
var index = 0;
// callback function
function tryMe (param1) { 
    waitFor(function(){return param1 == index}, 
            function(){console.log(param1);
                       index++;
                      }
    )   
} 

// callback executer 
function callbackTester (callback,i) {     
    setTimeout( function(){callback(i);}, 20000 - i*1000); 
} 

// test function
for(var i=0 ; i<10 ; i++){
    callbackTester ( tryMe,i );
}

function waitFor(fnReady, fnCallback) {
    var check = function() {
        if (fnReady()) {
            fnCallback();
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(check, 100);  // wait another 100ms, and try again
        }
    };

    check();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x061dx75/17/