# how to add additional argument to getJson callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, arguments

I have following function:

```
  $.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
      var items = [];
      $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
       ...
    });
}
```

How can I pass additional parameter to function?

I want something like this:

```
var newParam = externalFunction();
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data,newParam ) {
          alert(newParam);
          $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
           ...
        });
    }
```

Comment: I want to make something like this:http://stackoverflow.com/a/26698262/2674303

Comment: I can't invoke it from callback because at the time of the callback execution externalFunction() can return another value. actual value - at the moment of request sending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you need is to create a closure:

```
var newParam = externalFunction();

$.getJSON('http://date.jsontest.com/', (function (newParam) {
    return function (data) {
      alert(newParam);
      $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
       ...
      });
    }}(newParam)));
```

The closure will capture the value of `newParam` just when `$.getJSON` was called.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pen128tg/14/

Comment: I want to see 1 in alert

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dbwrge14/3/

Comment: I was wrong) above working example

Comment: Just in case it is helpful too: http://jsfiddle.net/pen128tg/17/

Comment: x=1;
setTimeout( function(){
$.getJSON( "test.js", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } )
  .fail(function (param) {
    return callbackHandler }(x));
},1000);
x=2;

function callbackHandler(data) {
      alert(param);
      alert(data)
}

Comment: please help me refactor this code:http://jsfiddle.net/pen128tg/18/

Comment: Hope this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/pen128tg/20/

Answer (score 0):

```
var newParam = externalFunction();

$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data) {
              alert(newParam); //in this case newParam is available
              $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
               ...
            });
       });
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp;

Comment: this function can be invoke a lot of times. I think at this way I will get fresh value

Comment: this code:  var index, _i;

for (index = _i = 0; _i < 10; index = ++_i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    return log(index);
  }, 1000);
}    returns 10 a lot of time

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x3wfbxr3/1/

Comment: expected result: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Comment: What are you trying to do?

by the time that anonymous function triggers, the global scoped index, will always be 10;

Comment: yes but why are you delaying the trigger?

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/x3wfbxr3/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pen128tg/8/

Comment: I don't know how to write analog for getJson

Comment: **why are you delaying the trigger?** - because json response I get with random and occasional delay