# how to add additional argument to getJson callback for non anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, arguments, data-transfer

I have following working code:

```
newParam=1;
$.getJSON('http://date.jsontest.com/', (function (x) {
    return function (data) {
      alert(x);     
    }}(newParam)));

newParam=2;
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kf040vp5/3/)

I want to make internal function non anonymous. but I cannot:

```
newParam=1;
$.getJSON('http://date.jsontest.com/', (function (x) {
    return func ;}(newParam)));

newParam=2;

function func(data) {
      alert(x);     
    }
```

message: `x is not defined`

Please help to refactor this code.

Comment: Try `return func.bind(null, x);`. Or simply `$.getJSON('http://date.jsontest.com/', func.bind(null, newParam));`.

Comment: x is not defined http://jsfiddle.net/x0eqpv6f/7/

Comment: what is the higher level issue you are trying to resolve?

Comment: @gstackoverflow Of course it's not defined, because it' `data` http://jsfiddle.net/x0eqpv6f/10/

Comment: @dfsq I need alert and json from server and x

Comment: @charlietfl this problem related with following question http://stackoverflow.com/q/26692776/2674303

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the inner function to have access to the outer function's scope (in this case, the `x` argument), you need the inner to actually be declared in the outer, like this:

```
newParam=1;
$.getJSON('http://date.jsontest.com/', funcFactory(newParam));

function funcFactory(x) {
  return function func(data) {
      alert(x);     
  };
}
```

Or you can modify your second example to use `.bind()` as suggested by dfsq but with some tweaks - use it to set the `this` object but *not* the arguments (because jQuery will set the arguments when it calls it with the result of the JSON request):

```
newParam=1;
$.getJSON('http://date.jsontest.com/', function (x) {
    return func.bind({param: x});
}(newParam));

newParam=2;

function func(data) {
   alert(this.param);   // note use of this
   alert(data);     
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x0eqpv6f/11/

Although if you're going to use `.bind()` you don't need the anonymous function at all:

```
$.getJSON('http://date.jsontest.com/', func.bind({param: newParam}));

function func(data) {
   alert(this.param); // note use of this
   alert(data);     
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x0eqpv6f/12/

Comment: And which difference with my first example in question?

Comment: You said you didn't want it to be anonymous, so that's what I gave you - along with a (brief) explanation as to why your second example wouldn't work.

Comment: now my function func declared in another place and I cannot redeclare it in each callback